# VueJS two-way data binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to dynamically change `amount` and `total` values using Vue's two way data binding. For a given product `price` is fixed. When users change `amount`, `total = amount * total` will be calculated. Similarly users can enter `total` and `amount = total / price` will be calculated. I am lost at this point:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    amount: 1,
    price: 100,
  },
  computed: {
    calcTotal: function() {
      return this.total =
        parseFloat(this.amount) *
        parseFloat(this.price)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  amount: <input v-model="amount"> <br><br> price: <input v-model="price" disabled> <br><br> total: <input v-model="calcTotal"> <br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: Your question title is far too generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the computed property (`calcTotal`), you can [listen](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) to the [`input`-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) from the `<input>`s for `amount` and `total`:

```
<input type="number" v-model="amount" @input="onAmountChange">
<input type="number" v-model="total" @input="onTotalChange">
```

The handler for `amount`'s `<input>` would set the value of `total`'s `<input>`, and vice versa:

```
  data() {
    return {
      amount: 0,
      total: 0,
      price: 100,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onTotalChange(e) {
      const total = e.currentTarget.value;
      this.amount = total / this.price;
    },
    onAmountChange(e) {
      const amount = e.currentTarget.value;
      this.total = amount * this.price;
    }
  }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      amount: 0,
      total: 0,
      price: 100,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onTotalChange(e) {
      const total = e.currentTarget.value;
      this.amount = total / this.price;
    },
    onAmountChange(e) {
      const amount = e.currentTarget.value;
      this.total = amount * this.price;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>amount: <input type="number" v-model="amount" @input="onAmountChange"></div>
  <div>price: <input type="number" v-model="price" disabled></div>
  <div>total: <input type="number" v-model="total" @input="onTotalChange"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot @tony19. How do I initiate with an amount value (let's say 1) so that total is displayed when page first loads. Now page loads with `amount=0` and `total=0`, but I'd like to start with an amount value.

Comment: @russell No problem :)  Regarding initial values for `amount` and `total`, just change those values in `data()`.